# Add footer to HTML page

Tags: html, html-table, footer

My index.html is mostly a table, and I would like to have one last row (TR) always at the bottom, doesn't matter the browser, or the screen size.

I tried using this as the last row in the `<table>`, but it does not work:

```
<tfoot>
  <td height=30>(c) My Company, 2011</td>
</tfoot>
```

What do you recommend to me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<tfoot>
<tr>
  <td height=30>&copy; My Company, 2011</td>
</tr>
</tfoot>
```

You forgot the tr tags

Comment: use `&copy;` instead of '(C)'

Comment: Thanks! I thought <tfoot> was a substitute for <tr>.

Comment: @Arturo, no problem I had this problem in the past, so this was an easy one for me glad to help.